# View C++ shared_ptr content in debugger

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

Debugging C++ code in xcode, Is there a way to view the contents of std::shared_ptr ?

if I look at the 'watch' window all I can see is __ptr = (element_type *) 0xa66945c

and writing 'po myPointer' in immediate window also print only the memory address.

I also tried the 'view Memory of "__ptr_"' and 'view Memory of "*__ptr_"' but it only lets me see

raw memory and no actual readable text

Can anyone suggest a way to view the object I have a pointer for ?

Comment: Did you try `po *(myPointer.__ptr)`?

Comment: I tried, it tells me :
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory

Answer (score 1):

The `fr` command in LLDB has a `--ptr-depth` argument, which can help in these situations.  For example, try typing this into the immediate pane:

`fr var myPointer --ptr-depth=1`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to hardcode in a std::cout statement to display the contents of the object (if any)...

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on __ptr_ and choose "View value as" -> "Custom type"

In the field that pops replace element_type with the actual type that std::shared_ptr points to.

I find it ridiculous that something like this does not works by default.